# How do I bind to itemAdded event of a drop down using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm adding elements to a drop down using jQuery. Currently I'm adding new items using below which is working fine:

```
$("#treatmentGroupDropDown").append(new Option(tempGroupName, tempGroupIndex));
```

However I want to create and subscribe to the itemAdded event which I've tried using the code below, but this isn't working:

```
$("#treatmentGroupDropDown").bind('itemAdded', function (event, item) { alert('item added: ' + item.toString()); });
```

Will something like this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some thing like this -

```
$("#treatmentGroupDropDown").bind('itemAdded', function(event, item) {
    alert('item added: ' + $(item).val());
});

var option = new Option("Test", "Test")
$("#treatmentGroupDropDown").append(option);
$('#treatmentGroupDropDown').trigger('itemAdded', option);
```

This will trigger the 'itemAdded' event after the new option has been appended, passing the option object that has just been created to the function.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/MxD25/

Answer (score 1):

The [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function doesn't have any `itemAdded` event.

Instead, you'd better add the function you want to trigger after the statement that appended your new Option.